# Можно переписать данный метод под switch?

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

```
    private string ReadableFileSize()
    {
        LoadFileInfo();
        var length = _info.Length;
        
        if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 1)) 
            return length + " B";               //lower than 1kb
        if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 2)) 
            return TrimSize(length, 1) + " KB"; //lower than 1mb
        if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 3)) 
            return TrimSize(length, 2) + " MB"; //lower than 1gb
        if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 4)) 
            return TrimSize(length, 3) + " GB"; //lower than 1tb

        return length + " TB";//return size in tb    
    }
```

Comment: можно, но зачем?

Comment: Я думаю  что свич более  выглядеть читабельным чем if. Хотя под капотом он преобразуется if :)

Comment: Я на вашем месте подумал бы не о том, как поменять шило на мыло, а о том, как убрать дубликаты и сократить вовсе код. Например, [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281679/6808809), как видите, `if` вдруг и вовсе не нужны, да и код кажется более логичным, да?)

Comment: [case guards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression#case-guards)

Comment: Велосипед уже придуман :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246708/373567 @EvgeniyZ кстати на заметку

Comment: Мне больше нравиться вариант @EvgeniyZ. Вариант aepot чем плох надо выделять целый класс(но идея не плохая). Тема с case guards интересная изучу спасибо Grundy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private string GetFileSize()
    {
        LoadFileInfo();
        
        var length = _info.Length;
        string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        var order = 0;
        
        while (length >= 1024 && order < sizes.Length - 1) 
        {
            order++;
            length /= 1024;
        }
        
        var result = $"{length:0.##} {sizes[order]}";

        return result;
    }
```