Информация о процессе. Event
Есть программа "ProcessExplorer", которая показывает список процессов и дает возможность посмотреть информацию об связанных dll, потоках процесса и (врядли так можно назвать, точно не знаю) о дескрипторах, список которых мне и нужен. В конечном итоге мне нужно получить возможность закрыть один дескриптор типа event, но как его получить, без понятия. Я смог получить списки dll и потоков через System.Diagnostics.Process, но стало понятно, что не все так просто. Буду благодарен за помощь :)


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1515954/373567 пока это всё что есть, а вопрос не понял.

На скрине, что я приложил, снизу список элементов что как либо связаны с процессом, имеющие разные типы. Мне нужно получить те же элементы что и показывает эта программа, но в моем c# коде. Без понятия как получить их. Может мне нужно получить весь этот список и из него их и брать, может элементы каждого типа получаются разными методами... Не знаю. Поэтому уточнил, что цель - получить один элемент с типом "event", и иметь возможность закрыть его, что может сделать эта программа. В общем хочу сделать то, что можно сделать в этой программе, но только в своей.

вероятно через WMI запросы это надо делать
