# Проблема с Timout HttpClient c#

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, httpclient, .net-8

При отправки запроса на rest веб сайта тяжелого файла упирался в ошибку таймаута "The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing."
Исправил данным образом:

```
    public static HttpClient _client = HttpClientGenerator(20);

    private static HttpClient HttpClientGenerator(int TimeOut)
    {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler,false);
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeOut);
            return httpClient;
    }
```

Но, такой большой таймаут не нужен хочу определять его от размера файла

```
if (MB < 500)
    _client = HttpClientGenerator(10);
else if (MB < 14000)
    _client = HttpClientGenerator(20);
else
    _client = HttpClientGenerator(30);
```

Проблема в том что появляется ошибка - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "An error occurred while sending the request."
InvalidOperationException: Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.
Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Добавление к ответу:`Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов:  [Внешний код] App.Resources.Net.Rest_API.RestService.E24SendFileBase.AnonymousMethod__0(int) в RestService.cs App.Resources.Net.Rest_API.ProgressStreamContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(System.IO.Stream, System.Net.TransportContext) в ProgressStreamContent.cs [Внешний код]`

Метод который отправляет данные на веб ресурс:

```
    public static async Task<string> E24SendFileBase(string file, string fileName, ProgressBar progressBar, System.Windows.Controls.Label label) а
    {

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()) 
        {
            var progressContent = new ProgressStreamContent(new StreamContent(System.IO.File.OpenRead(file)), progress: progress => 
            {
                progressBar.Value = progress;
                label.Content = $"{progress} %";

            }, totalBytesRead: totalBytesRead =>
            {
                label.Content += $" {totalBytesRead} /";
            }, totalBytes: totalBytes =>
            {
                label.Content += $" {totalBytes}";
            });

            switch (fileName.Remove(0, fileName.IndexOf(".") + 1))  
            {
                case "zip":
                    progressContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/zip");
                    break;
                case "dt":
                    progressContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"); 
                    break;
                case "1CD":
                    progressContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"); 
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


            ulong MB = Convert.ToUInt64(progressContent.Headers.ContentLength) >> 20;

            /*if (MB < 500)
                _client = HttpClientGenerator(10);
            else if (MB < 14000)
                _client = HttpClientGenerator(20);
            else
                _client = HttpClientGenerator(30);*/


            content.Add(progressContent, name: "FILE_BASE", fileName: $"{fileName}");


            using (var message = await _client.PostAsync("https://fake/rest//fake/", content))
            {
                return message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
            }
        }
```

Класс `ProgressStreamContent`

```
 public class ProgressStreamContent : HttpContent
 {
     private readonly HttpContent _content;
     private readonly Action<int> _progress;
     private readonly Action<string> _totalBytesRead;
     private readonly Action<string> _totalBytes;
     public ProgressStreamContent(HttpContent content, Action<int> progress, Action<string> totalBytesRead, Action<string> totalBytes)
     {
         _content = content;
         _progress = progress;
         _totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead;
         _totalBytes = totalBytes;
     }

     protected override async Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
     {
         var buffer = new byte[4096];
         var totalBytesRead = 0L;

         using (var inputStream = await _content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
         {
             var totalBytes = inputStream.Length;
             var bytesRead = 0;

             while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
             {
                 await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                 totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                 var progress = (int)((double)totalBytesRead / totalBytes * 100);
                 _progress(progress);
                 _totalBytesRead(SizeSuffix(totalBytesRead));
                 _totalBytes(SizeSuffix(totalBytes));
             }
         }
     }

     protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
     {
         length = _content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault();
         return true;
     }

     static readonly string[] SizeSuffixes =
               { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };

     static string SizeSuffix(Int64 value, int decimalPlaces = 1)
     {
         if (value < 0) { return "-" + SizeSuffix(-value, decimalPlaces); }

         int i = 0;
         decimal dValue = (decimal)value;
         while (Math.Round(dValue, decimalPlaces) >= 1000)
         {
             dValue /= 1024;
             i++;
         }

         return string.Format("{0:n" + decimalPlaces + "} {1}", dValue, SizeSuffixes[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Не нужно плодить HttpClientHandler. Нужно "чинить" HttpClient. 1) пилим [TimeoutHandler](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/) для поддержки таймаута для операции 2) пилим extension методы для HttpClient чтобы были всякие SendAsync с параметром timeout (или наследуем HttpClient и добавляем что нам надо). Так же решаем и другие неудобства HttpClient

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение! Сейчас попробую переделать.

Comment: Ну это все же костыль. Ведь нужно следить чтобы никто не изменил общий таймаут у клиента. Да еще и ловить нужное исключение. Увы, HttpClient фундаментально кривой

Comment: Тогда что можно попробовать вместо него IHttpClientFactory  или  WebClient ?

Comment: @Extro `WebClient` и прочие `HttpWebRequest` устарели, умерли и разложились. _Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту_ - это исключение не относится к `HttpClient`, его вызывает что-то другое, например попытка взаимодействия с UI-объектами из стороннего потока.

Comment: Мне непонятно, откуда такая проблема, что таймаута почти в 2 минуты - мало? Вы как-то странно нецелевым образом используете клиент? Пробовали включить HTTP/2? Сжатие трафика? Никаких таймаутов при отправке файлов не должно быть. Надо видеть код, который падает с исключением этим. Версия дотнета и операционной системы какая?

Comment: @aepot мало конечно. Сервер обычно ограничивает скорость и времени нужно много. А задать общий большой таймаут - в чем смысл тогда вообще таймаута. Плодить несколько клиентов под разные запросы - дичь, менять таймаут перед запросом - дичь. Вот и приходится изворачиваться добавляя методы параметром таймаут.

Comment: @vitidev таймаут при активной передаче данных не вызывается. Таймаут вызывается только при отсутствии передачи данных. Я гигабайты лил на сервер, никаких исключений не наблюдал, на дефолтных настройках клиента. Автор не сообщил, что у него за операционная система и версия дотнета. Если Framework 4.x - ответ очевиден.

Comment: @aepot Может там такой хитрый сервер, что он что-то с данными предварительно делает, пакует их там не знаю или ещё что-то хитрое. Чем больше запрашиваемые данные - тем дольше он думает перед отправкой. Это бы что-то могло объяснить. Хотя, конечно, хрень какая-то по большому счёту, сервер не должен так себя вести. А паковать данные можно и "на лету".

Comment: @aepot "Таймаут вызывается только при отсутствии передачи данных" - ничего подобного. Там используется CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(_timeout) и ему плевать на передачу данных. Не успела передача - будет исключение.

Comment: @vitidev Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на исходники, которые вы смотрели. Интересно, от какой они версии `.NET`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Не понимаю просьбы. Есть пакет System.Net.Http (для 4.8 его нужно ставить самому, а в остальном он есть в дистре). в нем используется CancelAfter и никакого различия для фреймворков у него нет. Ну разве что в первой версии что на нюгете нашело от 12года используется таймер + явный CTS.Cancel(). Так что выбирайте в гугле любые исходники. А про "таймаут при неактивности" это ServicePointManager.MaxIdleTime/ConnectionLeaseTimeout

Comment: .NET SDK 8.0.200
Windows 10

Comment: Как я и говорил, вы нарушаете потокобезопастность UI, вместо `Action<int> progress` используйте `Progress<T>`, вызывать так: `_progress.Report(progress);`. Ошибка _"Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту"_ уйдёт. Конструктор `progress: new Progress<int>(progress => { progressBar.Value = progress; label.Content = $"{progress} %"; })` должен вызываться в UI потоке. Кстати, вот вам решение по отображению мега-кило-байт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246708/373567