Сконвертировать число (MB) в (GB) математическим способом
Есть число в мегабайтах, к примеру 2189MB
Нужно это число превратить в : 2.1376953125 GiB
Как пример, нашёл на одном ресурсе формулу:
2189 x 2^-10 = 2.1376953125
Как это реализовать в C# ?

Вопрос кажется тривиальным, как 2189 умножить на (1/1024). В чем именно у вас затруднения?

int res = 2189 * 1/1024 - выходит 2, но, мегабайт в общем-то больше чем 2 гб. Мне нужен точный результат или как число 2189MB превратить в результат в GB (точный)

Ну если нужен ТОЧНЫЙ результат, то INT в качестве типа данных смотрится глуповатенько. мегабайт в общем-то больше чем 2 гб Вот даже не знаю, что на это сказать...

Так вопрос как сконвертировать-то ?

double gib = 2189 / 1024d

int res - вы используете инт, он может быть 2 или 3, но 2,1276.. вы в него никак не можете положить, он же инт )

Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246708/373567

Умножить на 2^10 это умножить на 1024. 2^-10 это 1/1024, то есть разделить на 1024. Вот и вся математика. Ну и использовать double вместо int.

Не получится потому что соотношение другое между MB и GiB. Тот результат что вы ожидаете соответствует соотношению MiB к GiB.
1 GiB = 1024·1024·1024 B
1 MB = 1000·1000 B
2189 MB = 2189·1000·1000 B
2189 MB = ((2189·1000·1000) / (1024·1024·1024)) GiB ~= 2.0386651158332825 GiB
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const double MB_to_B = 1000 * 1000;
        const double GiB_to_B = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        const double B_to_GiB = 1 / GiB_to_B;
        double v = 2189;
        Console.WriteLine(v * MB_to_B * B_to_GiB);
    }
}


$ csc /nologo temp.cs

$ mono temp.exe
2.03866511583328


P.S. По числам в вопросе можно догадаться что все множители в программе двоичные. Принципы те же, код другой:
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const double MB_to_GB = 1.0 / 1024.0;
        double v = 2189;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}GB", v * MB_to_GB);
    }
}


$ csc /nologo temp.cs

$ mono temp.exe
2.14GB



MB это же мегабиты, получается, а не мегабайты.

@aepot, MB означает мегабайт. Тут в вопросе всё согласовано верно.

А можно теперь получить результат ввиде 2.**GB ?

Я вот стесняюсь спросить: с какого перепуга 1 мегабайт = 1000 * 1000 байт? 1 Мб = 2^20 байт = 1024 килобайт = 1024*1024 байт

@Ingvar, мегабайт исторически использовался  с обоими множителями. Я выбрал десятичный множитель потому что в вопросе явно упомянуты MB и GiB. GiB - новая нотация, значит ТС использует новую нотацию, в которой MB десятичный и отличается от двоичного MiB.

Вероятно автор не обратил внимания/опечатался, в заголовке вопроса у него MB и GB. Десятичная насколько мне известно только для измерения скорости связи используется, и то с битами. С байтами редко. Ответ, кмк избыточен, стоило у автора спросить, имеет ли он представление об этих нотациях.

@aepot, я с вами согласен. Да, думаю, автор нечаянно использовал GiB и вся нотация двоичная. Но спрашивать скучно, а водить за нос весело. Десятичная ещё в объёмах дисков и (недавно прочитал) в Windows Explorer.

Я написал так, как выдаёт программа, к примеру пишет осталось 2189M и думай чего или что. Я начал ковертировать онлайн данную цифру  примерно сопоставляя с размером файла.
